# ActiveMQ Artemis: Get a list of all queues

Tags: activemq-artemis

There is an option in artemis web console to get list of all queues.

```
http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%22localhost%22/listQueues(java.lang.String,int,int)
```

How can I get list of all queues using curl command with passing this above url or is there any other way to get list of all queue?

I am using artemis 2.11.0

Comment: Good question, wondered about that as well. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `listQueues` operation is useful to filter or paging the list of the queues. It has 3 parameters `options`, `page`, and `pageSize`. The `options` is a JSON string to filter the queues, ie {"field": "", "operation": "", "value": ""}. The `page` and `pageSize` parameters allow to paging the result, ie to get the first 100 queues that contain in the name `TEST`:

```
curl -H "Origin:${REQUEST_ORIGIN}" -u admin:admin http://${BROKER_ENDPOINT}/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%22${BROKER_NAME}%22/listQueues/%7B%22field%22:%22name%22%2C%22operation%22:%22CONTAINS%22%2C%22value%22:%22TEST%22%7D/1/100
```

${REQUEST_ORIGIN} is the request origin matching the restriction defined by the tag `allow-origin` in the `jolokia-access.xml` file.

${BROKER_ENDPOINT} is the endpoint of broker HTTP Server defined by the attribute `bind` of the tag `web` in the `bootstrap.xml` file.

${BROKER_NAME} is the broker name defined by the tag `name` in the `broker.xml` file.

Using the default values, the command becomes:

```
curl -H "Origin:http://localhost" -u admin:admin http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/listQueues/%7B%22field%22:%22name%22%2C%22operation%22:%22CONTAINS%22%2C%22value%22:%22TEST%22%7D/1/100
```

Answer (score 1):

The `listQueues` method is really for the `artemis queue stat` command available from the command-line. It takes special input parameters to support paged output and various return parameters.

If you want to get a list of queues from the broker your best option would be the `getQueueNames` method. You can use something like the following `curl` command:

```
curl -s -k --user admin:admin -H "Origin: http://localhost:8161" "http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%22localhost%22/QueueNames"
```